# Reliably waiting for page to load 2

Tags: sdk, awesomium

How completely detect when awesomium browser end rendering the page? I try use this code, but its not correct detect it. In SO i can't find answer.

```
bool LoadingFinished;

    Wb.LoadingFrameComplete += WbLoadingFrameCompleted;
    ...

void WbLoadingFrameCompleted(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsMainFrame)
        return;

    LoadingFinished = true;
}

void LoadUrl(string url)
{
    LoadingFinished = false;

    Wb.Source = new Uri(url);

    while (!LoadingFinished)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        WebCore.Update(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after changing url:

```
while (!webControl.IsDocumentReady)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your webView implementing the `IWebView` interface you can subscribe to the *DocumentReady* event:

```
webView.DocumentReady += DocumentReady;
```

Your event handler

```
private void DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e){
    LoadingFinished = true;
}
```

Please mind that the Awesomium project is quite dead at this very momenent (see [homepage](http://www.awesomium.com/) currently stating only "We're building something new!"). You could also consider using another framework like [CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/overview) or [CefSharp](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/overview)